Why doesn't this Kotlin-backed FXML element get initialized or displayed?
I want to write reusable, composable JavaFX/FXML components in Kotlin. I am using Java 21 and my JavaFX is provided by gradle at version 22.0.1
My main class is loading the initial scene in a window via FXMLLoader.load and I see evidence of that. However, the skeleton custom component that is part of that scene graph is not displaying.
The custom component's controller's init {} does get invoked, but no combination of implementing/not implementing Initializable with/without arguments causes initialize() to be invoked. I have tried extending Control and VBox, and using fx:root and VBox for my root element.
How can I correct this? Is there a current and reasonably thorough resource that introduces FXML with Kotlin? I have tried everything I've found in the Oracle resources and 3rd-party blog posts that remotely matches my scenario, but it's not working.
This is the top-level scene, which does display in a window and I see "Test1".
// Launcher.fxml loaded via FXMLLoader.load in Main.kt

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?package project.ui?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import project.ui.LauncherPanel?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="project.ui.Launcher"
      prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <Label>Test1</Label>
    <LauncherPanel/>
</VBox>

However, the inner element doesn't seem to be initialized and "Test2" is not displayed. I have tried using fx:root and just VBox as the root element.
// LauncherPanel.fxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?package project.ui?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="project.ui.LauncherPanel">
    <Label text="Test2"/>
</fx:root>

This code-behind does seem to be somewhat implicated, since its init {} gets called but its initialize() does not under any combination of advice I have applied. I have also tried adding @FXML to initialize(), and tried extending Control and VBox with and without implementing Initialize, with and without parameters to initialize, with both fx:root and VBox as the FXML root element, per various advice.
//LauncherPanel.kt

package project.ui

import javafx.fxml.Initializable
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import java.net.URL
import java.util.*

class LauncherPanel: VBox(), Initializable {
    init {
        println("init gets invoked")
    }
    
    override fun initialize(p0: URL?, p1: ResourceBundle?) {
        println("initialize is not invoked")
    }
}


Why implement the deprecated @Initalizable interface? "This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of location and resources properties into the controller. FXMLLoader will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg initialize() method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection approach be used whenever possible.".

"I have also tried ... with and without implementing Initializable ..."

Then seperately, if it is a "custom component", then why not use the fx:root construct as documented in Creating a Custom Control with FXML?

"I have also tried ... with both fx:root and VBox as the FXML root element, per various advice" including that article (as it is in the code shown) but anyway that article is for Java 8 and JavaFX 8, and more recent examples seem not to call for manually invoking FXMLLoader when the fx:controller is set in FXML as in that article, which indicates to me that it is perhaps out of date, although I tried that, too.

But the code you have in the question, won't work for either case as far as I can tell (I can't speak to code not shown and I don't know Kotlin so I could be wrong).

Thanks, could you explain why not?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

FXML
The definitive source on how FXML works is the Introduction to FXML document.
There are also quite a few tutorials for FXML. One of them is the Oracle tutorial. That tutorial was written for JavaFX 8, but not much about FXML has changed since then so it's still applicable. The biggest change is what you need to do if deploying your application as a Java module. Another good tutorial is the JavaFX Tutorials on jenkov.com, which is actually linked to on https://openjfx.io.
The Problem in Your Code
When the FXMLLoader sees the <LauncherPanel/> element in the FXML file, it will simply try to instantiate the type by reflectively invoking one of its constructors; in this case it will be the no-argument constructor. But that's it. Nothing about that element or the LauncherPanel class indicates any additional FXML should be loaded. That means the class is not being instantiated as an FXML controller, let alone as an FXML root, and thus the initialize method is not being invoked.
Reusable FXML Components
There are two ways to create reusable FXML components: fx:root and fx:include.
fx:root
You use fx:root when you want to hide the use of FXML. You create a custom class which has its object graph defined in an FXML file, but code using the custom class does not know this. When you use this approach, you must:

Have fx:root as the root element of the FXML file.

Define the type attribute in the root element. The Introduction to FXML document sets the value of this attribute to the class which the custom class extends.

Manually set the root of the FXMLLoader. If the controller should be the same instance as the root, then manually set the loader's controller as well; do not define the fx:controller attribute in this case. Otherwise, if the root and controller are different classes, then you can use fx:controller. Which approach you use is up to you.

Load the FXML in the custom class's constructor.


You then use the custom class like any other.
Since this is the approach you attempt in your question, there is a full example of using fx:root below.
fx:include
Using fx:include is more straightforward. There's nothing special about the FXML file you include. It doesn't use fx:root, it can define an fx:controller attribute like normal, and you don't link it to a custom class. All you need is:
<fx:include source="<path to reusable FXML file>"/>

Whenever you want to nest one FXML file in another.
Note this approach is not just for creating reusable FXML components. Sometimes you may simply want to split a monolith FXML file into multiple smaller FXML files for maintainability.
Controller Initialization
Note that the Initializable interface, while not technically deprecated, is obsolete. From its documentation:

NOTE This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of location and resources properties into the controller. FXMLLoader will now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg initialize() method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection approach be used whenever possible.

That means the preferred approach looks like:
import javafx.fxml.FXML
import java.net.URL
import java.util.ResourceBundle

class Controller {

    @FXML private lateinit var location: URL
    @FXML private lateinit var resources: ResourceBundle

    @FXML
    private fun initialize() {
       // perform any needed initialization
    }
}

Both the location and resources properties and the initialize method are all individually optional. Only include them when you need them.
Note if your controller is capable of working with a ResourceBundle but can also function when a bundle is not specified, then you should define the property like so:
@FXML private var resources: ResourceBundle? = null


Example - fx:root
Here is a working example using fx:root with a Kotlin class, where the "root type" is used in another FXML file (like in your question).
The example was developed using:

Java 22.0.1

JavaFX 22.0.1

Gradle 8.8

Windows 11


Directory Layout
<project-directory>
|   build.gradle.kts
|   gradlew
|   gradlew.bat
|   settings.gradle.kts
|
+---gradle 
|   \---wrapper
|           gradle-wrapper.jar
|           gradle-wrapper.properties
|           
\---src
    \---main
        +---kotlin
        |       LauncherPanel.kt
        |       Main.kt
        |       
        \---resources
                LauncherPanel.fxml
                Main.fxml

Kotlin Sources
Main.kt
package com.example.fxmlsample

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.stage.Stage
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.Parent

fun main(args: Array<out String>) {
  Application.launch(Main::class.java, *args)
}

class Main : Application() {

  override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    val loader = FXMLLoader().apply {
      location = Main::class.java.getResource("/Main.fxml")!!
    }
    primaryStage.scene = Scene(loader.load<Parent>())
    primaryStage.title = "FXML Sample"
    primaryStage.show()
  }
}

LauncherPanel.kt
package com.example.fxmlsample

import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader

class LauncherPanel : StackPane() {

  @FXML
  private lateinit var label: Label

  init {
    val loader = FXMLLoader().apply {
      location = LauncherPanel::class.java.getResource("/LauncherPanel.fxml")!!
      setRoot(this@LauncherPanel)
      setController(this@LauncherPanel)
    }
    loader.load<LauncherPanel>()
  }

  @FXML
  private fun initialize() {
    label.text = "Hello, from 'initialize'!"
  }
}

FXML Files
Main.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.example.fxmlsample.LauncherPanel?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      spacing="10" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefWidth="500" prefHeight="300">
  <padding>
    <Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/>
  </padding>
  <Label text="FXML Sample"/>
  <Separator/>
  <LauncherPanel VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
</VBox>

LauncherPanel.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.StackPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <Label fx:id="label"/>
</fx:root>

Gradle Files
settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "fxml-sample"

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "2.0.0"
  id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.1.0"
  application
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.1.0"

repositories { 
  mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
  modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
  version = "22.0.1"
}

application {
  mainClass = "com.example.fxmlsample.MainKt"
}


Note that the use of fx:root and fx:controller are essentially orthogonal. There is no requirement for the dynamic root to also act as the controller: you can use fx:root and call setRoot(this), but also use fx:controller and define a separate controller class in the usual way. This probably makes the class implementing the dynamic root very thin, but it still hides the use of FXML and maintains separation between the FXML controller and the view (albeit with some tight coupling between the two).
